# default button not work for asp.net panel

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, defaultbutton

I have a aspx page that has a master page, in this page I have an asp.net panel and I want when I press enter search button fire,but it doesn't work.
I test many solutions: set

```
this.Master.Page.Form.DefaultButton = this.btnAdd.UniqueID
```

but not worked,

set asp:panel defaultbutton,but it is not working,

set

```
this.Master.Page.Form.DefaultFocus = this.Mypanel.UniqueID
```

but not work...
how can I solve this problem (without using jquery)?

Comment: Something like this should work. Try without "this.Master", just use "this". Otherwise, post the whole page code.

Comment: @Olaf thank you,my problem solved! I test again and it is ok! without above codes,only with set DefaultButton of asp:Panel :)